# how to get order_id from razorpay in ionic 5?

Tags: android, ionic5, razorpay

```
   var options = {
      description: 'Credits towards consultation',
      image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
      //order_id: 'order_DBJOWzybf0sJbb',
      currency: 'INR',
      key: 'yourKey',
      amount: '100',
      name: 'Acme Corp',
      prefill: {
        email: '',
        contact: '',
        name: '',
      },
      theme: {
        color: '#df2929'
      },

      modal: {
        ondismiss: function () {
          alert('dismissed')
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order id  get by Api provider backend server.

Answer (score 0):

For any setup (ionic/react/any) we would need to create the order_id through a api post call to Razorpay server.

please refer - https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order